# High response time vs queuing

Tags: http, web, microservices

Say I have a webserivce used internally by other webservices with an average response time of 1 minute. 
What are the pros and cons of such a service with "synchronous" responses versus making the service return id of the request, process it in the background and make the clients poll for results?

Is there any cons with HTTP connections which stay active for more than one minute? Does the default keep alive of TCP matters here?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application  it may matter. Couple of things worth mentioning are !

**HTTP protocol is sync**

There is very wide misconception that HTTP is async. Http is synchronous protocol but your client could deal it async. E.g. when you call any service using http, your http client may schedule is on the background thread (async). However The http call will be waiting until either it's timeout or response is back , during all this time the http call chain is awaiting synchronously.

**Sockets**

Since HTTP uses socket and there is hard limit on sockets. Every HTTP connection (if created new every time) opens up new socket . if you have hundreds of requests at a time you can image how many http calls are scheduled synchronously and you may run of sockets.  Not sure for other operation system but on windows even if you are done with request sockets they are not disposed straight away and stay for couple of mins.

**Network Connectivity**

Keeping http connection alive for long is not recommended. What if you loose network partially or completely ? your http request would timeout and you won't know the status at all.

Keeping all these things in mind it's better to schedule long running tasks on background process.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the user waiting while your long job is running on server, you are tying up a valuable HTTP connection while waiting.

Best practice from RestFul point of view is to reply an HTTP 202 (Accepted) and return a response with the link to poll.

If you want to hang the client while waiting, you should set a request timeout at the client end.

If you've some Firewalls in between, that might drop connections if they are inactive for some time.

Answer (score 0):

**Higher Response Throughput**

Typically, you would want your OLTP (Web Server) to respond quickly as possible, Since your queuing the task on the background, your web server can handle more requests which results to higher response throughput and processing capabilities.

**More Memory Friendly**

Queuing long running task on background jobs via messaging queues, prevents abusive usage of web server memory. This is good because it will increase the Out of memory threshold of your application.

**More Resilient to Server Crash**

If you queue task on the background and something goes wrong, the job can be queued to a dead-letter queue which helps you to ultimately fix problems and re-process the request that caused your unhandled exceptions.